# this command is not available because no document is open

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the code below. It is working on my computer but when we run on the server I get an error>

> this command is not available because no document is open.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

```
fUpload.SaveAs(strPathToUpload + "\\" + fUpload.FileName);

                    //open the file internally in word. In the method all the parameters should be passed by object reference
                    objWord.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing);
                    //Do the background activity
                    objWord.Visible = false;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument;
                    oDoc.SaveAs(ref FileToSave, ref fltDocFormat, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have Word install on the server?
2. Do the versions are the same on your PC and on the server?
3. In the first line you are opening a document, what is the Filename value? Maybe the file is not saved on the filesystem and then when trying to set oDoc as Activedocument, it fails

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using word interop with ASP.NET, [that library is not designed to work with a non-interactive session](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) (Running inside a service like IIS) and you cannot reliably use it like you want to.

You should be using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to manipulate word documents in a server setting. See the KB article in my first link to many, many, tutorials on how to use it in the "*Alternatives to server-side Automation*" section.